# Partitioned Runge-Kutta (Lobatto IIIAB)

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis

I am wondering, if anybody knows some paper, that study convergence and stability of Partitioned Rung-Kutta Methods (especially Lobatto IIIAB) applied on separable Hamiltonian system.

Answer (score 2):

Google says:

- L. Abia and J. M. Sanz-Serna, *Partitioned Runge-Kutta Methods for Separable Hamiltonian Problems*, Mathematics of Computation Vol. 60, No. 202 (Apr., 1993), pp. 617-634, [doi:10.2307/2153105](https://doi.org/10.2307/2153105).

Answer (score 0):

The paper

- R. I. McLachlan, Y. Sun, and P. S. P. Tse, *Linear Stability of Partitioned Runge–Kutta Methods*, SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis Vol. 49, Iss. 1 (2011) 232-263, [doi:10.1137/100787234](https://doi.org/10.1137/100787234)

addresses explicitly linear separable Hamiltonian ODEs and re-uses some results from the older paper

- Laurent O. Jay and Linda R. Petzold, *Highly Oscillatory Systems and Periodic-Stability*, Preprint 95-015, Army High Performance Computing Research Center, Stanford, CA, 1995, [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Linda-Petzold/publication/2266559_Highly_Oscillatory_Systems_and_Periodic-Stability/links/0912f50cabdcada5c7000000/Highly-Oscillatory-Systems-and-Periodic-Stability.pdf).